# segmentation fault during memcpy

Tags: c, reverse, memcpy, memmove

I am trying to make a function which reverses the order of a portion of a string. I'm new to using pointers and for some reason I can access the location of the characters of my string to copy out a substring, but I can't put them back into the same location...

When I try to copy the reversed substring back into its original location I get

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b5dc66 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Any help would be awesome!

Here's what I have so far:

```
void reverse(char* line, int start, int end){

      char str[end-start];

      memcpy ( str , line + start , end-start );

      reverseSubString ( str );

      memcpy ( line + start, str , end-start );

}

void reverseSubString(char* str){

    int i, j, len;
    char temp;

    i=j=len=temp=0;

    len=strlen(str);

    for (i=0, j=len-1; i<=j; i++, j--)
    {
        temp=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just reverse your substring in place, rather than copying it, reversing it, and copying it? Pass a length argument to reverseSubString, instead of using strlen (which is the source of your bug anyway, as mentioned in the answers below).

Comment: reverseSubString executes without a problem, but I see where you're coming from. I've made the changes to incorporate a more "solid" length but the second memcpy still causes a segmentation fault. I originally tried to reverse it in place was hitting the same problem.

Comment: "reverseSubString executes without a problem" -- No, it certainly doesn't ... not on an arbitrary sequence of chars that aren't NUL-terminated. "I originally tried to reverse it in place was hitting the same problem" -- then you should have tried to understand and solve that problem, rather than adding pointless copies to and fro.

Answer (score 3):

```
  char str[end-start];

  memcpy ( str , line + start , end-start );
```

Unless the 0-terminator of the original string is included, you have a `char` array that is not 0-terminated. So

```
len=strlen(str);
```

computes who-knows-what if that doesn't already crash. Then

```
for (i=0, j=len-1; i<=j; i++, j--)
{
    temp=str[i];
    str[i]=str[j];
    str[j]=temp;
}
```

accesses outside the allocated memory.

Comment: reverseSubString executes without a problem, but I see where you're coming from. I've made the changes to incorporate a more "solid" length but the second memcpy still causes a segmentation fault. I originally tried to reverse it in place was hitting the same problem.

Comment: Ends up my string was being declared in non-modifiable memory! Easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

`reverseSubstring()` expects a NUL-terminated C string, because it calls `strlen()` on the string passed in. However, you fail to NUL-terminate your string in the `reverse` function. Either do that, or even better, pass in a `length` argument:

```
void reverseSubString(char *str, size_t len)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp;

    for (i = 0, j = len - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
    }
}

void reverse(char *line, int start, int end)
{
    char str[end - start];
    memcpy(str, line + start, end - start);
    reverseSubString(str, end - start);
    memcpy (line + start, str, end - start);
}
```

Comment: `reverseSubString(line+start, end-start)` would have the same effect ... no need for the `memcpy`'s and the VLA.

Comment: @JimBalter Of course, but I didn't say it's needed either - I just fixed the mistake. To be honest, I didn't even think about the running time of the code (since I focused on the error). This code works, and making it faster wasn't my intention, after all (OP also has to worry about making it work before trying to make it fast).

Comment: The point is that it would be good to point out that this code is far more complex and error-prone (and inefficient) than it need be, rather than just include it without comment. As for "making it work before trying to make it fast" -- it's a lot easier to make code work when it doesn't do a lot of unnecessary operations. There's a huge difference between writing code that is directed at the problem, and thereby happens to not only be simpler but also more efficient, and twiddling with code in ways that "make it faster" but aren't problem oriented; I was only talking about the former.

Comment: `for (i = 0, j = len; i < j; i++, j--)` looks nicer to me, and by intuition I'd say it's also saver ... ;-) You could also savely declare `i` and `j` to (also) be `size_t` this way. Anyway +1 for the most suitable approach passing the length down to the reverse function ...

Comment: @alk Same comment to you as to Jim Balter :) I don't bother rewriting all of OP's code. He should make an effort too.

Comment: @alk That's not safer, it's UB ... on the first iteration str[j] is undefined. As for H2CO3's response: again, "it would be good to point out ..." -- nothing there about the OP not having to make an effort. We've got rank beginners coming here and pointing out problems with their code makes them better programmers and the world a better place, especially if they actually end up writing code for a living.

Comment: @JimBalter: Oouch, yes, you are right ... - I apologize for the bad, because wrong advice.

Comment: @alk It works if you decr j before the exchange rather than after, but that doesn't fit as nicely with C's `for` syntax.